# How to get the value of a div using javascript in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I have many divs that were generated in a foreach, and i have to get the value of this divs.

```
@model Recall

@foreach (var veiculo in Model)
                        {
                            <div value="@veiculo.Veiculo.Vin" class="chassi-importado" id="myDiv">
                                @veiculo.Veiculo.Vin
                                <i name="icon-remover-um-chassi" class="bx bx-x-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                        }
```

I´ve trying to use the following code in javascript, but i am getting a null value in the list. How can i get the correct value?

```
 let veiculos = [];

 $.each($('.chassi-importado'),
                function () {
                veiculos.push({ vin: $(".chassi-importado").val() });
            });
```

Comment: do you mean the content of a div? you can get values of a form input not div

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation https://api.jquery.com/each/ `$.each` passes `index` and `element` params into the callback provided by you but you don't use them. Also, instead of `val()` you need to use `text()` to retrieve `innerText` value. `val()` is used mostly for `inputs`.

Here is what you need to do instead:

```
 let veiculos = [];

 $.each($('.chassi-importado'),
   function (index, element) {
     veiculos.push({ vin: $(element).text() });
   }
 );
```

Even better would be to utilize `map` because you are not just traversing through elements but extracting their values.
Here is how you can do this:

```
 let veiculos = $.map($('.chassi-importado'), (el) => $(el).text());
```